# Store git fetch output in a txt file

Tags: git, batch-file

I want to store the output of this command in a text file and this was my attempt:

```
git fetch -v --dry-run >test.txt
```

All what happens is it continues to write to the console and creates an empty txt file. 
On a high level, I am writing a batch file to determine if there are changes to update my local copy of the repository.

Answer (score 9):

The output is written to stderr, not to stdout. So you have to add `2>&1` to the command line.

Answer (score 4):

```
git fetch -v --dry-run >test.txt 2>&1
```

or, my preferred method:

```
git fetch -v --dry-run |& tee test.txt
```

The `|&` requires a recent bash